# How to verify a plane is parallel to a line?

Tags: vectors, parametric

Plane equation is: $$7x-5y+2z-9=0$$

Line parametric form:
$x=t, y=-4+3t, z=9-4t$

Comment: The equation of the plane gives you a normal to it. If a line is parallel to said plane, it must be perpendicular to this normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Construct the surface normal of the plane, $\hat{n}$
2. Find the vector direction of the line, $\vec{v}$
3. If $\hat{n} \cdot \vec{v} = 0 $, then the surface normal is perpendicular to the line, so the line is parallel to the plane

Comment: If the line happens to be contained within the plane, then it will (of course) be perpendicular to the surface normal...but we would not say the line and plane are parallel in this case.

Comment: (...At least, I wouldn't call them parallel.  In the same way that I don't consider a line to be parallel to itself, even though it has the same slope as itself.)

Answer (score 1):

You could just substitute for $x$, $y$ and $z$, and see if there's any solutions.